# How to automatically close rasterio raster histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, rasterio

I want to automatically save some histograms from raster data as images as png and I am using `rasterio`.

My question is how to save `histogram images` without needing to show the histogram (because then I have to close the figure manual) or how to close the figure automatically with code.

Thanks.

```py
    from rasterio.plot import show_hist
    raster='image path'
    fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
    show_hist(raster, bins=50, lw=0.0, stacked=False, alpha=0.3,
          histtype='stepfilled', title="Histogram")
    
    fig.savefig(path)
```